# PHP: generating html code with a for loop that won´t show up in page source?

Tags: php, post, for-loop, foreach

**I want to generate some HTML code (a form with several text inputs, actually) with a for loop.**

I´ve tried two ways (with and without an array).

After the expected output appears into the screen, I try to view it using the browser´s "page source" utility, but even when the html code shows up into the screen *it won´t show up into the page source*.

WHY?

**After filling the form inputs created with the for loop, I then try to get the information using $_POST, but nothing actually prints out**... Maybe because of the same reason it won´t appear at the page source?

ie. typing this produces nothing: `echo $_POST['fmes1'];`

### This is my first try:

```
  $numOrder=1; 
  $mes=1;
  $anio=1;

for ($i=0; $i<$cantMeses; $i++) { 
    $celdas = array(
        $i => 'Mes <input name="fmes'.$mes.' class="ancho-celda2"> 
                   Año <input name="fanio'.$anio.' class="ancho-celda">',
                    );
        foreach ($celdas as $elemento) {
            echo $numOrder.' '.$elemento.'<br>';
        }
$numOrder=$numOrder+1;
$mes=$mes+1;
$anio=$anio+1;
}
```

### And this is my second try, not using an array:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$cantMeses; $i++) { 
    echo "<br><b>".$numOrder. "º </b>
    Mes <input name='fmes".$mes." class='ancho-celda2'>  
    Año <input name='fanio".$anio." class='ancho-celda'> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    ";
}
    $numOrder=$numOrder+1;
    $mes=$mes+1;
    $anio=$anio+1;
```

### This is the form on calculadora.php:

```
<form onsubmit='return validar()' name="generar-tabla" action="calcular.php" method="POST">
    Calcular intereses hasta:
        Mes <?php echo '<b>'.$tMonth.'</b>';?>  
        Año <?php echo '<b>'.$tYear.'</b>';?>
        <br>Con tasa de Interés del <input value='<?php echo $interes;?>' type='text' name='interes' class="ancho-celda">% mensual
        <br>Cuántos meses se adeudan? <input type='text' name='cantMeses' class="ancho-celda" value="<?php echo $cantMeses;?>">
        <br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Generar tabla para cálculo'>
</form>
```

### And it goes to calcular.php:

(it is still very much empty, because I´m trying to get the information form the other form. I´cve tried using the same file too)

```
session_start();
include ('calculadora.php');

echo $_POST['fmes1'];
```

Comment: How did you use this `echo $_POST['fmes1'];` ? And rendered html code must be shown in page source. There is something wrong that you have missed

Comment: What doesn't show up in the page source?  The inputs, or your form output?  It's hard to know what is going on with your $_POST vars when you don't post any of the form processing logic. What browser are you using?

Comment: Some browsers won't display the source code if it was produced from ajax call. But it will show up if you use debugger.

Comment: Sorry about that. I´ve edited the post. I´m using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Add your form code, you might just be missing the `form` elements or the `action` attribute inside doesn't point to the page where you're trying to echo...

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, I can't see where are you closing the `for` loop. Besides, you are resetting the `$celdas` contents in each loop, when you should instead append to the array.

```
$numOrder=1; 
$mes=1;
$anio=1;
$celdas = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$cantMeses; $i++) { 
    $celdas[$i] = 'Mes <input name="fmes'.$mes.' class="ancho-celda2"> Año <input name="fanio'.$anio.' class="ancho-celda">';
}
foreach ($celdas as $elemento) {
    echo $numOrder.' '.$elemento.'<br>';
}
```

Anyway, I don't see why you need to perform a loop at all. The even if `$cantMeses` was set somewhere else, the contents of each `$celda` array element doesn't seem to depend on the month index. Perhaps the `$mes` variable should instead be the one to iterate? Something like

```
$numOrder=1; 
$anio=1;
$celdas = array();
for ($mes=1; $mes<=$cantMeses; $mes++) { 
    $celdas[$mes] = 'Mes <input name="fmes'.$mes.' class="ancho-celda2"> Año <input name="fanio'.$anio.' class="ancho-celda">';
}
foreach ($celdas as $mes=>$elemento) {
    echo $mes.': '.$numOrder.' '.$elemento.'<br>';
}
```

This is just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Maybe it won´t retain the value because of that. But using $celdas[$i]= instead of $celdas= will print out just the word array...